# How to clean output, prints the desired information with less CPU usage

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have 20GB log file, where it contains lots of fields, the field or column numbers 2 contains numbers. I use the below commands to print only column 2

```
zcat /path to file location/$date*/logfile_*.dat.zip | awk '/Read:ROP/' | nawk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

the result of this command is:

```
"93711994166", Key
```

since i want only the number then i append the below command to my original command to clean the output:

`| awk -F,  '{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g`'

the result is:

```
93711994166
```

my final purpose is to print only numbers having length other than 11 digits, therefore, I append the following to my final command:

```
 -vE '^.{11}$'
```

so my final command is:

```
zcat /path to file location/$date*/logfile_*.dat.zip | awk '/Read:ROP/' | nawk -F "=" '{print $2}' | awk -F,  '{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g' | grep -vE '^.{11}$' >/tmp/$file
```

this command takes long time to execute also causes high CPU usage. I want to achieve the following:

- print all numbers with length not equal to 11 digits.
- print all numbers that do not start with 93 (regardless of their length)
- clean, effective and not cpu or memory costly command

I have another requirement which is to print also the numbers that not started with `93`.

Note:

the log file contains lots of different lines but i use `awk '/Read:ROP/'` to work on the below output and extract numbers

```
  Read:ROP (CustomerId="93700001865", Key=1, ActiveEndDate=2025-01-19 20:12:22, FirstCallDate=2018-01-08 12:30:30, IsFirstCallPassed=true, IsLocked=false, LTH={Data=["1|
    MOC|07.07.2020 09:18:58|48000.0|119||OnPeakAccountID|480|19250||", "1|RECHARGE|04.07.2020 10:18:32|-4500.0|0|0", "1|RECHARGE|04.07.2020 10:18:59|-4500.0|0|0"], Index=0
    }, LanguageID=2, LastKnownPeriod="Active", LastRechargeAmount=4500, LastRechargeDate=2020-07-04 10:18:59, VoucherRchFraudCounter=0, c_BlockPAYG=true, s_PackageKeyCount
    er=13, s_OfferId="xyz", OnPeakAccountID_FU={Balance=18850});
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then, that will be helpful for testing of solutions.

Comment: I have edited my question with the required info

Answer (score 0):

> 20GB log file [...] `zcat`

Using `zcat` on 20GB log files is quite expensive. Check `top` when running your command line above.

It might be worth keeping the data from the first filtering step:

`zcat /path to file location/$date*/logfile_*.dat.zip | awk '/Read:ROP/' > filter_data.out`

and work with the filtered data. I assume here that this awk step can remove the majority of the data.

Bonus points: This step can be parallelized by running the `zcat [...] |awk [...]` pipe file-by-file, and you only need to do this once for each file.

The other steps don't look particularly expensive unless there are a *lot* of data lines left even after filtering.

Comment: I will be greatfull if you type the entire command in bonus point you have mentioned also please comment about 1st and 2nd points on my question

Comment: Now that I think of it, bash would be a poor choice for parallelizing commands. `make` would be much better suited - it can parallelize tasks, and even check whether the filtering step is *needed* at all based on file dates. Very much ot-of-scope here, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/.*Read:ROP.*([^=]="\([^"]*\)".*/!d; s//\1/'
```

- `/.../` - match regex

  - `.*Read:ROP.*` - match `Read:ROP` followed by anything with anything in front, ie. `awk '/Read:ROP/'`
  - `([^=]*="` - match a `(`, followed by anything except `=`, then a `=`,  then a `"`, ie. `nawk -F "=" '{print $2}'`
  - `\([^"]*\)` - match everythjing inside qoutes. I guess `[0-9]` would be fine also
  - `".*` - delete rest of line
- `!` - if the line doesn't match the regex

  - `d` - remove the line
- `s` - substitute

  - `//` - reuse the regex in `/.../`
  - `\1` - substitute for first backreference, ie. for `\([^"]*\)`